# Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Profile> but Array<(out) Parcelable!>? was expected Navigation graph

Tags: kotlin, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList<Profile>` in a bundle from one fragment to another using the Navigation Graph, but I am getting this error `Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Profile> but Array<(out) Parcelable!>? was expected` I have already passed on the navigation the type of argument that I want to pass. What am I missing? Here my code

Code that passes the argument

```
 emptyHomeViewModel.playerByIDLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { profile ->
                    if (profile != null) {
                        profilesList.add(profile)
                        bundle = Bundle().apply {
                            putSerializable("user", profilesList)
                        }
                        findNavController().navigate(
                            R.id.action_emptyHomeFragment_to_selectUserFragment,
                            bundle
                        )
```

Navigation XML for the fragment that will receive

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectUserFragment"
        android:name="com.example.dota2statistics.SelectUserFragment"
        android:label="fragment_select_user"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_select_user" >
        <argument
            android:name="user"
            app:argType="com.example.dota2statistics.data.models.byID.Profile[]" />
    </fragment>
```

Code of the fragment that receives the ArrayList

```
class SelectUserFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_select_user) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val args : SelectUserFragmentArgs by navArgs()
        val profilesList = args.user

        Log.i("Profiles", "onViewCreated: ${profilesList[0].personaname} ================")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

add this plugin

```
plugins {
     id("kotlin-parcelize")
}
```

then make your class parcelable for example

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int): Parcelable
```

Safe args only allows passing Array so before adding bundle we have to convert ArrayList to Array

```
bundle.putParcelableArray("user", profilesList.toTypedArray())
```

Then when getting the argument we can convert it back to ArrayList

```
val list: ArrayList<Profile> = ArrayList(args.user.toList())
```

Comment: Ok that fixed it, but now when I try to switch screens I get this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'user' in argument bundle. [Lcom.example.dota2statistics.data.models.byID.Profile; expected.
        at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.addInDefaultArgs(NavDestination.java:635)

Comment: I updated the answer and tested it is working, I forget that you are trying to pass ArrayList with safe args so we are converting ArrayList to Array for passing.

Comment: Correct again!! I love you and respect you already, thank you so much!!!